# Evaluating$\int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}$

Tags: integration, quadratics, rational-functions

This is the integral:

$\int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}$

I have tried several ways to solve this but I always end up that last parameter equals 1 and all others equals 0 so I end up where I started. Examples over the internet with similar fraction have more than $1$ in the numerator which makes the example simplier.

Here's what I tried

$\frac{A}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{(x+1)^2(x-1)^2}$ as ${(x^2-1)^2}=(x+1)(x-1)(x+1)(x-1)$

from there I got to point where

$A+B+C=1\\4B+C=1\\4A+C=1$

but this leads to $A=0,\ B=0$ and $C=1$ so to nowhere

I also tried this way:

$\frac{Ax+B}{(x^2-1)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2-1)^2}$

but this resulted into

$A = 0\\B=0\\-A+C=0\\-B+D=1$

so again I got $A=0,\ B=0,\ C=0$ and $D=1$ which led to nowhere.

How to tackle this problem?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{x^2 - 1}$ can be factored as $\frac{1}{x + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{x - 1}$, so all of the partial fractions terms have the form $\frac{A}{(x - \lambda)^k}$. Of course, one can still ask this question for, e.g., $\int \frac{1}{(x^2 + 1)^2} dx$, for which the denominator admits no such linear factorization over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Travis I think you meant over $\mathbb{R}$. There is a linear factorisation of the denominator over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Deepak Yes, that's what I meant of course, cheers.

Comment: You wanted to start with $\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{(x+1)^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Since:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right),$$
then:
$$\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{2}{(x-1)(x+1)}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right)$$
or:
$$\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right).$$
Better now?